# Can't load Spark static sub-directories

Tags: java, jetty, spark-java

Here's my problem:

- I'm using Spark as my web server framework in my Java project.
- My website is designed with the following structure:

  - Index.html
  - js Folder (with JavaScript libraries and files)
  - css folder (with styles)
  - Image folder (with pics)

I copied this structure into my "public" folder (under resources) just like in the Spark documentation. and added this folder as a static folder using:

```
staticFiles.location("/public");
init();
```

But now, only the files inside "/public" and the immediate-childs of the folders can be accessed, i.e:

- [localhost]:[port]/index.html - **works**
- [localhost]:[port]/js/main.js - **works**
- [localhost]:[port]/js/lib/lib.js - **DOESN'T WORK - 404**
- [localhost]:[port]/css/myTheme/greenTheme.css - **DOESN'T WORK - 404**

What should I do to include all sub-directories as static files?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
If I open a file that wasn't found in NetBeans, add a new line and saves the file - the file can later be found when I run the program! Any ideas for why's that?

Comment: have you found the reason for your problem? i just tried out myself and it worked out of the box. i am curious why it does not work for you.

Comment: Maybe a permissions problem for these directories?

Comment: @Yevgeniy It only works if I load static EXTERNAL folders, but if I want to load the files from a class file (putting all the files in a Java package) then it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SHG It's not a permission issue since the files are within my resources folder and have the same permission as the rest of the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever encounter this issue - you should:

1. clean your project.
2. build it again.
3. only then try to run it (clicking the Play button).

Worked for me (using NetBeans IDE).

Comment: your answer seems to make sense only in a context of a specific IDE. you should mention which IDE this is, but it sounds like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In the Intellij IDE, after making a modification, it was necessary to run a mvn clean install and restart the application.